# libvirt with xen server

Tags: xen, libvirt

I want to use libvirt with Xen-Server (not Xen-project). When I invoke the command 'virsh', I get the following error :

virsh

error: unable to connect to 'localhost:8000': Connection refused

error: failed to connect to the hypervisor

There is no   /etc/xen/xend-config.sexp file on the XEN-Server, where I can enable HTTP server.

XEN Server works fine as I can create and run VMs properly using XEN-Center.

How do I configure XEN-Server to accept connection from libvirt ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this question remains unanswered after some time...

XenServer (as far as I know) does not support Libvirt in this manner. XenServer uses a different toolstack (`xe`) than Xen Project (`xm` or `xl`).

Xen Project's `xm` toolstack utilizes the `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` file, which contains these two configuration lines:

```
(xend-http-server yes)
(xend-port 8000)
```

When using Xen Project with the `xm` toolstack, libvirt requires the above two lines to be configured as such in order to open the port for Libvirt to properly connect to the Xen instance. If using Xen Project's `xl` toolstack, Libvirt should be able to automatically connect to Xen without needing to modify any configuration files.

Since you aren't running the `xm` toolstack (and likely can't install it on XenServer), I would say the answer to your question is **it can't be done**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting xen with ssh

Eg:

```
virsh -c xen+ssh://root@machineNameOrAddress list
```

or

```
virsh -c xen+ssh://root@machineNameOrAddress help host
```

Although it's not a good long term strategy. If that doesn't work, try turning off selinux. To do this edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux change to SELINUX=disabled. If it works after that, it sounds like you might need to edit your port permissions.

Another sanity check, can you shell into the Xen machine with ssh? What happens when you status these services: xenconsoled, xendomains, xen-init-dom0, xen-qemu-dom0-disk-backend, xen-watchdog, xenstored, libvirtd, libvirtd-guests? They should all come back SUCCESS if you are using libvirt with xen. If they do not, are they not finding libs they need etc. Track those down and installl them.